# JavaScript function with interval doesn't work for the first time

Tags: javascript

I want to run the function renews() with interval but want to run first time when the html is opened. so I wrote renews(); but it doesn't work. I could run other function of the code. but only this one doesn't.
Thank you for the help!

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script>

        var i=0;
        var u=0; //0:redy for the next FX
        var newstext;

        function renews() {

            if(i%2==0){
                newstext = "aaa";
            } else {
                newstext = "bbb";
            }
                document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = newstext;
                i++;
        }
        //renews(); // this doesn't work
        setInterval(function(){
        renews();
        },3000);
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span id ="news">test</span>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). Classical error: the DOM isn’t loaded yet, so you can’t access `document.getElementById("news")`.

Comment: @Xufox that's really not a duplicate question. Dupes are determined by the _question_ not by the _answer._

Comment: Try putting your code below the `body` tag, it might mean the DOM elements have not rendered yet

Comment: Please watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ, because you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your script to the bottom of the body. When you execute your script, the DOM has not been build yet, and thus there is no element to operate on.

Comment: the function runs in a timeout. It *may* not be parsed yet, but with such a minimal page it would be a safe bet to assume the element is parsed after the 3 second timeout.

Comment: Yes, but as I read the question, the problem is that it won't run _at all_ until after 3 seconds...

Comment: @rlemon There’s a commented-out line in the question. That’s the line that doesn’t work and at that time the DOM hasn’t loaded yet.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much everyone. so does it mean If JavaScript was separated file, then I always should put JavaScript loading after main body of html?

Answer (score 0):

When you’re dealing with the DOM it’s important to execute your code only after the page is fully loaded. If you don’t, there’s a good chance the DOM won’t be
created by the time your code executes.

Now Let’s think about what just happened when your code run. you put your js code in the header tag of the page, so it begins executing before the browser even sees the rest of the page. That’s a big problem because that span element with an id of “news” doesn’t exist, yet.

So what happened exactly? The call to getElementById returns **null** instead of the element you want, causing an error, and the browser, being the good sport that it is, just keeps moving and renders the page anyway, but without the change to the DOM at the first time.

How do you fix this? Well, you could move your code to the bottom of the body, but **there’s actually a more foolproof way to make sure this code runs at the right time;** a way to tell the browser “run my code after you’ve fully loaded in the page and created the DOM.” Besides moving the code to the bottom of the body, there’s another—and, one might argue—cleaner way to do it with code.

Here’s how it works: first create a function that has the code you’d like
executed once the page is fully loaded. After you’ve done that, you take the
**window** object, and assign the function to its **onload** property. The window object will call any function you’ve assigned to its onload property, but only after the page is fully loaded. Check This out:-

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

    var i=0;
    var u=0; //0:redy for the next FX
    var newstext;

    function renews() {

        if(i%2==0){
            newstext = "aaa";
        } else {
            newstext = "bbb";
        }
            document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = newstext;
            i++;
    }
    //renews(); // this doesn't work
    window.onload = renews; //But this will work
    setInterval(function(){
    renews();
    },3000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id ="news">test</span>
</body>
```

Now even if you put your JavaScript code in a separated JS file and import it in the header tag instead of moving it to the end of the body your code will work just fine.